# How to pass multiple parameter values form URL to same Razor view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here I try to update the URL from a tag by asp-route and get the value in same Razor view.

```
<a asp-route-id="1" asp-route-notification="Receive"></a>
```

Then I try to access the value in bottom of the page with,

```
@{var id = Context.Request.RouteValues["id"];
var notification = Context.Request.RouteValues["notification"];
}
```

But this was return only id value. I couldn't get the notification parameter value. I want to get both values in same Razor view. Thanks in Advance.